# How does PVC actually work when it's attached to a deployment with multiple replicas?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

My Kubernetes deployment has a PVC attached, and it has 3 replicas. I was trying to understand what it actually means. 3 replicas are all on different nodes, in different zones, but the pods can access the same piece of storage at the same time.

So my question is that where the physical disk locates? If it's with say node 1 in zone 1, then how does node in zone 2 access it without network? If it requires network, then it's possible that the data will not be synced? What if I have a worker node in Dallas and another one in London? Are they still able to access the same PV and update at the same time?

I was trying to use it to store some cache data because looks like it's accessible to all the pods, but there were too many questions in my mind that I can't get over. Thanks for any insightful answers in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) is an abstraction. PV works with different storage system and they may have different properties. E.g. the [Storage Class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) you are using may hint if it is available in all your Zones in a cloud Region or only one Zone. Also [Access Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) of your PersistentVolume affect wether all your pods can access the volume concurrently from different Nodes or not.

In most cases, a PV is only available in a single Zone and on a single Node at a time. But e.g. PVs backed by e.g. NFS may be available from multiple Nodes and Zones.

When using `PersistentVolume` from a `Deployment`, all your replicas refers to the *same* volume. Depending on your storage system, this may be problematic, if using more than one replica.

When using `StatefulSet`, all your replicas refers to their own *unique* volume.

For using *cache* in a distributed environment like Kubernetes, I would consider using something that is distributed and accessible over the network, e.g. [Redis](https://redis.io/).

> where the physical disk locates?

This depends on what storage system is configured for your *Storage Class*, but usually it is something located on another server, e.g. [AWS EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) or [Google Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk)

> If it's with say node 1 in zone 1, then how does node in zone 2 access it without network? If it requires network, then it's possible that the data will not be synced?

PVs that are available in multiple Zones are typically synced synchronously (e.g. a trade off with higher write latency), but only to another nearby located Zone. If you need geo-replicated data, it would be better to consider something asynchronous, e.g. [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see so indeed if a PVC can be shared across nodes, it's not the traditional disks anymore, rather, cloud storage. So would better off just configuring/using some actual "caching server". The reason I didn't think about Redis in the first place is that my caches are all files (> 10Mb~ ) so didn't think Redis would be a good fit. Would the speed of sending binaries to redis the same/similar as using shared PV considering they are all through network? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Keno for caching files in a cloud environment, it is common to use "Buckets", e.g. AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage.